# Azure table storage range query with commonly used condition wrapped in method

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a common occurence in my application where I create a query to get all entities where partitionkey is constant but rowkey should be within an lexical range (e.g. only rows which start with some prefix):

```
//query to get all entities in partition "KnownPartition" where RowKey starts with "Prefix_"
CloudTableQuery<MyEntity> query =
    (from e in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(tableName)
     where e.PartitionKey == "KnownPartition"
           && e.RowKey.CompareTo("Prefix_") > 0
           && e.RowKey.CompareTo("Prefix`") <= 0 // ` is '_' + 1
     select e).AsTableServiceQuery();
```

I must use CompareTo because string functions such as StartsWith are not supported in this kind of query. This works, but the condition is hard to read and repeated a lot. So instead of writing a lot of queries with this hard-to-read condition, I'd rather like to make a function which "inlined" it:

```
public static Boolean HasPrefix(this String rowKey, String prefix)
{
    return rowKey.CompareTo(prefix + '_') > 0 && rowKey.CompareTo(prefix + '`') <= 0;
}

CloudTableQuery<MyEntity> query =
    (from e in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(tableName)
     where e.PartitionKey == "KnownPartition" && e.RowKey.HasPrefix("Prefix")
     select e).AsTableServiceQuery();
```

But when I run this, I get an exception from Azure about my function not being supported. Is there any way to write this so that it is supported? After all, I'm using the exact same condition as the query that worked, just wrapped in a function...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you break the condition out into a function, then the function needs to return an expression tree rather than a boolean value.  I don't know if LINQ query syntax will support this, but you can do it with the method syntax as follows:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> HasPrefix(String prefix) 
{ 
    return e => e.RowKey.CompareTo(prefix + '_') > 0 && e.RowKey.CompareTo(prefix + '`') <= 0;
}

CloudTableQuery<MyEntity> query =
    (from e in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(tableName)
    where e.PartitionKey == "KnownPartition"
    select e)
    .Where(HasPrefix("Prefix"))
    .AsTableServiceQuery();
```

Comment: Very cool, this works. Thank you. I suppose we could just write the whole expression as a method chain rather than the linq query syntax to be constistent.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I hope this doesn't result in a full scan... As in, the actually transferred entities from azure has already been checked for the prefix condition, right?

Comment: The resulting Azure storage request URI is: https://foo.table.core.windows.net/tablename()?$filter=((PartitionKey eq 'KnownPartition') and (RowKey gt 'Prefix_')) and (RowKey le 'Prefix%60').  So only rows that meet all of the conditions will be returned.  Furthermore, because the query specifies the partition key and a range of row keys, a full table scan shouldn't be required on the back end either.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a generalization of Kevin's answer. It does the same thing, but works for any prefix string rather than just the specific case David asked about in the original question.

```
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> HasPrefix(String prefix) 
{ 
    char lastChar = prefix[prefix.Length - 1];
    char nextLastChar = (char)((int)lastChar + 1);
    string nextPrefix = prefix.Substring(0, prefix.Length - 1) + nextLastChar;

    return e => e.RowKey.CompareTo(prefix) >= 0 && e.RowKey.CompareTo(nextPrefix) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the generalized answer!  MS should have just included this bit in the linq query processor!